# Interface fields

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstraction

First, I currently understand that interface fields are static final in their implementation.

My current understanding is that interfaces allow for loosely connected classes to share methods of the same name, and that is quite helpful. Is there a standard for making loosely classes to share fields of the same name, but not have those fields be static finals?

Currently I have a group of classes which all extend from one parent class (sometimes through several child classes). A group of those child classes should contain a field, while another group does not need that field. All other parts of the parent class are shared by the children.

Comment: Why not make a hierarchy with two intermediate abstract classes between the top parent and the child classes? This way, the two abstract classes will declare the fields needed by each group and all child classes will extend one of those abstract classes.

Comment: Sounds like it would work.
Would you recommend I have the two abstract classes both extend from one (pretty much empty) class, or have one extend from the other?

Comment: I thought you wanted all your child classes to be subclasses of the same parent. So I suppose those two abstract classes will extend/implement the same interface or the same existing class.

Comment: Seems this will work for my needs, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

ernest_k has pointed out that you are able to have two classes which extend from a (pretty much empty) class. This works for what I am looking for.